# Handle different screen size for iOS Devices

Tags: ios, cordova, screen-size

I have spent two days for Phonegap-iOS tutorial to handle different screen size for iOS devices(iPhone4,iPhone5,iPad etc). I have not found any good tutorial for this.

I would appreciate for any help. Please let me know if any anyone has any idea on how to achieve it.

Thanks,
Nitin.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong you must be developing your front pages using HTML5? If so give height and width of elements in %. Your pages will automatically resize according to screen size. Search for responsive web design you will get a lot of stuff to read.
Another solution is to use media queries.

Comment: Thanks for your help...Please let me know if there is any simple working tutorial available.